# Excel Interop Service will not save workbook on clients machine

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, excel-interop

The problem I am having involves saving a workbook that is created in C# code on a clients machine. The published version of the program works perfectly on my machine, but not on the clients.

**Overview of the Process:**

When the program has completed it's iterations it will create worksheets once complete it will save the workbook and display a message box saying that the export was successful and display the workbook that was created.

**The Problem:**

When ran on the clients machine it will go through the process of creating the worksheets, but for some reason it will not save the file. It dose keep the instance of excel in memory, so when you open task manager you will see the process. Also after you run the program and try to turn off the computer it will prompt you to save or not save the workbook that was created since the instance is still in memory. This is how i have worked around and got to save the workbook to verify that the program did create the worksheets.

**My thoughts:**

I am thinking that there maybe some settings for windows or for excel that is preventing the excel file to be saved and automatically opened. I am also using background worker to accomplish the task of monitoring the progress of the workbook creation process, so this could also be a problem.

If anyone has encountered this problem or know of a solution please let me know. If more information is needed then i can provide that.

*I did not include code, because i did not find it useful in knowing why the problem is happening since everything works on my development machine, but not the clients.*

*EDIT*

I work with Jared and was finally able to debug the program on another machine with VS installed. It turns out that the problem wasn't in the save function at all but with the number of default sheets created on a client machine.

When creating the workbook, the program is supposed to go through the worksheets and delete all of them but the first one.  There was a logic flaw (coded by me :/) that would leave an empty sheet in the workbook which caused the problem at this statement:

```
int lastRow = _excelWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Row;
```

Apparently it doesn't like searching for stuff on an empty sheet. Our development machines are currently set to default to one sheet only, so we didn't run into the problem.

What I found odd was that while debugging, the program would throw a System.NullReferenceException at that line. However, the program wouldn't crash on the client machines.  Instead, it would just leave the Excel instance in memory as described and would just sit there.  As Jared said, the excel stuff runs on a background thread so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Might be a user permissions issue where he does not have permission to write to the file location.....

Comment: Have you tried the saveAs method?  It may be prompting the user to overwrite the file and programmatically you're not clicking yes to overwrite

Comment: **@PheonixReborn** - that's what i was thinking, but the file location is his desktop folder.

**@mikeMurf22**-It is using the SaveAs() method.

To be honest with this problem I have no idea where to start looking for answers. It just doesn't seem possible, because we have other programs that have been made to do almost the samething when it comes to saving excel workbooks, but yet this one doesn't work.